# jar with dependency (binscan). Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, ant

I have built an binscan.jar binary from a Java project [binscan](https://sourceforge.net/projects/binscan/):

> ant build.xml

Now I want to run the application:

> java -jar binscan.jar

But this command gives me the following error:

> java -jar binscan.jar
>
> Could not find or load main class org.sked.binscan.BinscanApp

I've read the questions on the stackoverflow about this error and tried to apply proposed solutions - but with no luck.

binscan requires appframework-1.0.3.jar to be built. But is appframework-1.0.3.jar required to run binscan.jar? Which would be the correct command to run binscan.jar?

And have the directory containing binscan.jar to be named accordinly to the package name org.sked.binscan?

What would be the steps to determine the cause of the error?
What should be checked about the output .jar file?
Is there any diagnostic options jar-file can be run with?

Comment: I would suggest that you add a manifest to your executable JAR to include the main class and set the CLASSPATH with JAR dependencies.  You can deploy the dependent JARs inside or outside your JAR.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: @duffymo Thank you for the comment. manifest is included in the binscan.jar automatically with a correct full class name. The following line is also contained in the manifest:

X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build.

Is it OK?

Comment: Looks like the manifest is already present, as Java seems to know that the jar’s main class is org.sked.binscan.BinscanApp.  Check whether the .jar file actually contains an `org/sked/binscan/BinscanApp.class` entry.

Comment: @VGR org/sked/binscan/BinscanApp.class is present. How then it could not be found or loaded?

Comment: I've tried to run org/sked/binscan/BinscanApp.class directly (instead of running .jar file), i.e. from the folder where .class files have been placed during building: java org.sked.binscan.BinscanApp. I still get the same error.